# How to access Java system properties from Freemarker templates?

Tags: java, freemarker, system-properties

I started using Freemarker for assembling simple HTML pages, using [FMPP Maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/freemarkerpp-maven-plugin/). So far so good.
But one thing I need to do is to include value of a system property (one of system properties Maven provides) on a page. Is there a way to access system properties from Freemarker templates?
(if not, I may just have to hack plugin to allow passing values from Maven)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FMPP has a [setting called `data`](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/settings.html#data) that specifies the variables that all templates will see, so that's where you should put the system properties. To put values into there, unless the value can be specified as a simple literal, you need a so called data-loader. So in this case you need a data-loader that returns the system properties as a `java.util.Properties` object. While there's no data-loader specifically for that, you can use the `eval` data-loader like this (in your `config.fmpp`):

```
data: {
   ...
   sysProps: eval('System.getProperties()')
   ...
}
```

Now in your templates you can access the system properties like `sysProps["os.name"]`.

Alternatively, you could write a custom FMPP data-loader. See http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/dataloader.html#sect19.

Answer (score 3):

cf https://community.jivesoftware.com/thread/14820

You can access it like this :

```
${statics['java.lang.System'].getProperty("my.property")}
```

cf documentation here : 
http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html

Comment: -1 you should at least read your copied comment at first before pasting it.

Comment: Hmmh. I guess I can accept this, although it does not quite work for me -- seems like I would need to register this from Java, which is not possible except by modifying plugin. So I might as well modify plugin directly.