# How to inject maven properties in Freemarker template?

Tags: spring, maven, freemarker

I need to use the value of "config.enableInstitutions" property in pom.xml to be used in Fremarker template as the value of a hidden input.

Pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <config.enableInstitutions>true</config.enableInstitutions>
    </properties>
```

myfreemarker.ftl

```
<body>
<input type="hidden" value="<< value of config.enableInstitutions property here >>"/>
```

How do I use that property in freemarker template?

Comment: Read [post1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394354/how-to-access-java-system-properties-from-freemarker-templates) and [post2](http://youhenghu.blogspot.in/2012/02/maven-substitution-and-freemarker.html)

Comment: Use it wisely: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28178768/1700321.